# D3 - Append rect if the text begins with character 'f', else append circle

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am trying to build a more dynamic tree, and each node in the tree has either a number like "7" or "13", or something like "f[10]". I used hollow circle with text in the middle in my tree. However, it looks bad because when the node has "f[10]", the text will spill out of the circle. I'm looking for something like this pseudocode:

```
For each data point:
    if data.txt.charAt(0) = 'f':
         append rect
         .attr("size", etc...
    else:
         append circle
         .attr("r", etc...
```

The attributes are important to me.

This is what my tree currently looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhYVK.png

And this is my js file in pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/yWZWdcP4

I use it to fill up

```
<div id="recursionTreeOne"></div>
```

in my `index.html` file.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You could use a](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter) `.filter`:

```
node.filter(function(d){
  return d.num.charAt(0) != 'f'
})
.append("svg:circle")
.attr("r", 10)
.attr("fill", "white")
.attr("stroke", "black")
.attr("stroke-width", "1");

node.filter(function(d){
  return d.num.charAt(0) == 'f'
})
.append("rect")
.attr("fill", "white")
.attr("stroke", "black")
.attr("stroke-width", "1")
.attr("width", 50)
.attr("height", 50)
.attr("x", -25)
.attr("y", -10);
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/aNH8rzRjR8xvQJISJYgK?p=preview).

Comment: 2022 here and this is the only that works, thanks!